# Modify object of Main activity array from upper positions of activity chain

Tags: android, android-activity, chain

I have a chain of activities: Act1->Act2->Act3. Act2 is a view displaying items from an array of objects in Act1, and Act3 is a view displaying data from the item clicked in Act2. With a longclick in Act2 an item can be deleted, and with a longclick in Act3 the data within an item can be modified. When deleting or modifying items I want to remain in the respective views with the updated data displayed.

How would I best achieve this? Would I make the object array in Act1 static or is there another way?

Comment: Send your updated data back and forth in relevant activities by using Intents.Search "passing data between activities" here or google.

Comment: Well I think a broadcast seems like what I want, and it works fine getting data from Acr3 back to Act1, but I'm not sure how to inform Act3 when Act1 has dealt with the broadcast, so that Act3 knows when to refresh its view. Do I have to send another broadcast back from Act1 to Act3?

Comment: I'll still stick with my suggestion. Although, seems like there is misunderstanding on either part. I request you to share few snippet of code here for to get a good understanding and help you out.